# Moving an element in 2d array

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

I am trying to move the false element in 2d array to a different blank space in element

```
'x''o'' '
' '' ''o'
'x''x''o'
```

the first element(x) in the array is false because it has no similar elements around it.
i am trying to figure it out using nested for loop but not getting the result
this is what i get

```
' ''o''x'
'x''x''o'
'x''x''o'
```

it moves that false x to all the blank spaces instead on just one blank space. Any tips please
this is my code.  I tried using break, but it does't work.
tissue is the array passed in with the elements

```
    char[][] arr = new char[tissue.length][tissue[0].length];
    int count = 0;
    char temp;
    for(int i=0; i<tissue.length; i++){
        for(int j=0; j<tissue[0].length; j++){
            if(!isSatisfied(tissue,i,j,threshold)){
                temp = tissue[i][j];
                for(int k=0; k<tissue.length; k++){
                    for(int l=0; l<tissue.length; l++){
                        if(tissue[k][l] == ' '){
                            tissue[i][j] = arr[k][l];
                            arr[k][l] = temp;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: what is this `tissue`? Could you post the definition of `tissue` i.e. delcaration and what value it has got? We want the tissue array that you are using.

Comment: tissue is the array passed in the method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to break the loop when it finds the first space for replace

```
 if(!isSatisfied(tissue,i,j,threshold)){
                    temp = tissue[i][j];
                    outer:
                    for(int k=0; k<tissue.length; k++){
                        for(int l=0; l<tissue.length; l++){
                            if(tissue[k][l] == ' '){
                                tissue[i][j] = arr[k][l];
                                arr[k][l] = temp;
                                break outer;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
```

Comment: Thank you.  But what does outer: means/do

Comment: outer is not a command. it is just a label for break point. you can use any word in that label

Answer (score 0):

First in

```
for(int l=0; l<tissue.length; l++){
```

It should be tissue[0].length ?

Second in

```
tissue[i][j] = arr[k][l];
```

arr should be initial before can be assigned to another variable.